# Need to edit tag to add hyphen

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I accidently created the tag azurewebjobs
All the Azure tags follow the convention azure-*
I'd like to stick to this convention, but I get the following error:

> You are attempting to create the tag [azure-webjobs](/questions/tagged/azure-webjobs); however the
>   tag [azurewebjobs](/questions/tagged/azurewebjobs) already exists. If
>   you think this new tag should be
>   allowed, raise it on meta.

Comment: @animunson please add an answer that can be accepted, so it doesn't come up in the [has no accepted answer search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=[retag-request]%20hasaccepted%3ano)